# Extract the department from a Person/Group field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, person

I'm working on a custom list where the user types in the person's name in the person/group field.  I'd like on saving the item, to have a workflow that runs that populates another field with the department that this person is with.

Is this possible with SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible.

I did this with a people picker field called "PeoplePicker" and a field called "Department" (single line of text) and used the workflow action called `Set field in current item`.

[image]

By obvious reasons i can't show you the result as i wish to remain anonymous, but can confirm that this works. (2010 workflow platform in a 2013 environment).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I had been trying.  I forgot to mention that we're using Active Directory for our people picker.  When I try select any field in the workflow, the only options in the "Return field as" the only values I can choose are: Display Name, Email Address, Login name and User Id Number.  No department.

I can create a second lookup field and get the user to type in the name of the person again and display the department, I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: I think that you are selecting the people picker field as this one returns those options. It's important that you select User Profiles as datasource as this got all the fields from your AD

Comment: Did it work out for you or do you have any questions?

Comment: I ended up having to go another way that solved my problem.  We actually created a department list and tagged an administrator's AD account to it, and a workflow fires to that administrator.

I'm going to keep your idea in my back pocket because I know I'm going to need it at some point.  Thanks for the assist.